I need help linking to images in my child theme - I'm trying to design a personalised login page and favicon to replace Wordpress logos
I have created a child theme that I'm going to install on my clients sites, the aim is to replace the Wordpress logo from the wp-admin page, as well as the favicon in the top left in the dashboard.
I've followed the steps from this article - https://cusmin.com/blog/wordpress-logo/#code-snippets
It seems to have all worked for the links, and it has removed the WordPress logos, but it isn't pulling through my logos. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?!
My image files are stored in the child theme, /img/Favicon.png & /img/Logo.png
<?php

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', [] );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 20 );

function avada_lang_setup() {
    $lang = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages';
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'Avada', $lang );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'avada_lang_setup' );


if( !function_exists( 'custom_admin_bar_logo_link' ) ){
  function custom_admin_bar_logo_link() {
      if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
          return;
      }
      echo "
      <script type='text/javascript'>
          (function(){
              document
                  .getElementById('wp-admin-bar-wp-logo')
                  .children[0]
                  .setAttribute('href', '#')
          })();
      </script>
      ";
  }
  add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_bar_logo_link'); //Trigger on backend
  add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_admin_bar_logo_link'); //Trigger on front-end
}

if( !function_exists( 'custom_login_logo' ) ){
  function custom_login_logo() {
      echo '<style>
          h1 a { background-image: url("<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/Logo.png") !important; }
      </style>';
  }
  add_action( 'login_head', 'custom_login_logo' );
}

if( ! function_exists( 'custom_login_logo_url' ) ){
  add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'custom_login_logo_url' );
  function custom_login_logo_url() {
      return '#';
  }
}

if( !function_exists( 'custom_admin_bar_logo' ) ) {
  function custom_admin_bar_logo()
  {
      if(!is_user_logged_in()){
          return;
      }
      echo '
      <style>
          #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon:before {
              background-image: url("<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/Favicon.png") !important;
              background-position: 0 0;
              color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
              background-size: contain;
          }
          #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo.hover > .ab-item .ab-icon {
              background-position: 0 0;
          }
      </style>
      ';
  }
  add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_bar_logo'); // for the back-end
  add_action('wp_head', 'custom_admin_bar_logo'); // for the front end
}

if( !function_exists('custom_remove_wp_links_under_the_logo') ) {
  function custom_remove_wp_links_under_the_logo() {
      if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
          return;
      }
      echo '
      <style>
          #wpadminbar .ab-top-menu>.menupop>.ab-sub-wrapper{
              display: none !important;
          }
      </style>
      ';
  }
  add_action('admin_head', 'custom_remove_wp_links_under_the_logo'); // Hide on backend
  add_action('wp_head', 'custom_remove_wp_links_under_the_logo'); // Hide on frontend
}


This syntax: url("<?php  cannot be used within php code itself. You are using it in a php string. It should only be used within html parts since denotes it that a piece of php is about to start.
